# C# WinForms - SQL Server Compact Edition : keyword not supported : initial catalog

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

I want to get data from a database server (SQL Server 2012) to write what I got into a local database (SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 - WinForms app - VS 2013)

- Create `.SDF` database file via code -> ok.
- Open local connection to `.SDF` file -> ok.
- Create table via code -> ok.
- Open connection to database server -> NOT ok ! :(

I got this error message :

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

Here is my code :

```
class MySqlCeEngine
{
    private const string LOCAL_SDF_FILE = "LocalDB.sdf";
    private const string LOCAL_CONN_STRING = "Data Source='|DataDirectory|LocalDB.sdf'; LCID=1033; Password=3C670F044A; Encrypt=TRUE;";
    private const string SOURCE_CONN_STRING = "Data Source=SQL\\SERVER;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;

    public static void CreateDB()
    {
        if (File.Exists(LOCAL_SDF_FILE))
        {
            File.Delete(LOCAL_SDF_FILE);
        }

        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(LOCAL_CONN_STRING);
        engine.CreateDatabase();
        engine.Dispose();

        SqlCeConnection localCnx = null;

        try
        {
            localCnx = new SqlCeConnection(LOCAL_CONN_STRING);
            localCnx.Open();

            SqlCeCommand localCmd = localCnx.CreateCommand();

            #region CREATE TABLE t_Address
            localCmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE t_Address(
                                    Address_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                    Address_Main nvarchar(4000) NULL,
                                    Address_CityName nvarchar(50) NULL,
                                    Address_CityZipCode nvarchar(50) NULL,
                                    Address_CountryID int NULL,
                                    Address_CustomerID int NULL,
                                    Address_SiteID int NULL,
                                    Address_IsVisible bit NOT NULL,
                                 CONSTRAINT PK_t_AdressID PRIMARY KEY (Address_ID)
                                )";

            localCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            #endregion

            using (SqlCeConnection sourceCnx = new SqlCeConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
            {
                try
                {
                    sourceCnx.Open();

                    SqlCeCommand SourceCmd = sourceCnx.CreateCommand();
                    SourceCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_Address";
                    SqlCeDataReader reader = SourceCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(LOCAL_CONN_STRING))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "t.Address";

                        try
                        {
                            // Write from the source (DB server) to the destination (local wibe)
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sourceCnx.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            localCnx.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I did some searches on the web and found that I should add "ProviderName=System.Data.SqlClient" but I still have this issue.

I also tried with the System.Data.Entity.Database class method "OpenConnectionString" but it doesn't work (VS tells me that this class does not contain a definition for this method).

I don't know what to do although I'm trying some things found here and there.

Thanks,

Hellcat

Comment: From the connection string, it seems that your `source` database is a bona fide Sql server instance. In which case you should be using a vanilla using `SqlConnection` to it - the `SqlCe*` types are just for your local SqlCe database.

Comment: OMG that's right ! I had my eyes burning while looking for a solution but it's just a mistake >< ! Gonna try with the right class. I hope it will be ok then, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection to the *full* SQL Server using `SOURCE_CONN_STRING` must use the `SqlConnection` - not the `SqlCeConnection` ...

So change this line:

```
using (SqlCeConnection sourceCnx = new SqlCeConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
```

to:

```
using (SqlConnection sourceCnx = new SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONN_STRING))
```

and use the `SqlCommand` (not the `SqlCeCommand`) when you're dealing with the full SQL Server instance.

Comment: Yea thank you ! But now it's my SqlBulkCopy which is not working. I got a "keyword not supported: lcid". Is there a CE version of SqlBulkCopy ?

Comment: I found this, if anybody would need it one day : http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/
Thanks again !